# Find the best pairs of elements based on match weight

Tags: performance, php, programming-challenge, sorting

While answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006832/generate-combinations-and-choose-best-based-on-three-parameters/) question on SO I came up with a very simple solution and I wanted to know if there were improvements that could be made to it.

The function takes an array of participants as inputs, generates a list of pairs using the array of participants with an associated score (to be generated by a function comparing the elements but for now using [rand()](http://php.net/rand)), then finds the the best possible match and return the results as an array (imagine students being matched for a team assignment).

```
function generatePairs($elements) {
    // $elements = [
    //     1,2,3,4,5,6    
    // ];

    $elementCount = count($elements);
    $output = [];

    // build an array with every unique possible pair
    $possiblePairs = [];
    for($i = 1; $i <= $elementCount; $i++) {
        for($j = $i + 1; $j <= $elementCount; $j++) {
            $possiblePairs[] = [
                'values' => [$elements[$i - 1], $elements[$j - 1]],
                'score' => rand(1, 100) // this would be replaced by a function calculating how closely the current elements match
            ];
        }
    }

    // puts the "best" pairs on top
    usort($possiblePairs, function($a, $b) {
        return $b['score'] <=> $a['score'];
    });

    $used = [];
    foreach($possiblePairs as $key => $pair) {
        if($pair['score'] !== 0 && 
            !in_array($pair['values'][0], $used) && 
            !in_array($pair['values'][1], $used)) 
        {
            // save the pair to the output array
            $output[] = $pair['values'];
            // store the elements that have already been used
            array_push($used, $pair['values'][0], $pair['values'][1]);
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple improvements:

#### Pop from array and iterate over remaining items in nested loop

I tried to modify the nested *for* statements used to add to `$possiblePairs` and use a functional approach like with [array_reduce()](http://php.net/array_reduce) but instead found the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3770387/1575353). Consider shifting (i.e. popping from the beginning) from the array to yield an array with the remaining elements with which to generate pairs.

```
while ($item = array_shift($elements)) {
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        //generate pair with $item and $element
```

With this approach, there is no need to keep track of counter variables (e.g. `$i`, `$j`), use those to index into the array, nor increment those until certain conditions change. It also makes the following line superfluous (so it can be removed):

```
$elementCount = count($elements);
```

#### Store pair as key, and score as value

This way the sorting can be simplified - using [asort()](http://php.net/asort) with [***SORT_NUMERIC***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#refsect1-function.sort-parameters) as `$sort_flag`. Then reverse the array for descending order using [array_reverse()](http://array_reverse).

```
while ($item = array_shift($elements)) {
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        $possiblePairs[$item.'_'.$element] =  rand(1, 100); 
    }
}
asort($possiblePairs, SORT_NUMERIC);
$possiblePairs = array_reverse($possiblePairs, true);
```

#### Output from keys

Because of the changes above, the keys are the pairs so use [list()](http://php.net/list) and [explode()](http://php.net/explode) to unpack the pairs.

```
$used = [];
    foreach($possiblePairs as $pair => $score) {
        list($element1, $element2) = explode('_', $pair);
        if($score !== 0 && 
            !in_array($element1, $used) && 
            !in_array($element2, $used)) 
        {
            // save the pair to the output array
            $output[] = [$element1, $element2];
            // store the elements that have already been used
            array_push($used, $element1, $element2);
        }
    }
    return $output;
```

#### Another optimization

In order to only go through the  (last) *foreach* loop as few times as necessary, the following conditional could be added after pushing values into `$used`:

```
if (count($used) == count($elements)) {
     break;
}
```

That should prevent excess loop iterations. While the difference may be negligible for small lists, it may be very helpful to reduce the execution time for larger lists.

### Demonstration

Check out [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/kl8KkUilT9LeZjLN) for a demonstration. And compare the time output at the end with [the original](https://www.tehplayground.com/nf7Ybs2EPnd6Qxmf).

```
| Run | Original             | Updated               |
|-----|----------------------|-----------------------|
|  1  | 0.0002138614654541s  | 0.00012707710266113s  | 
|  2  | 0.00021195411682129s | 0.00017905235290527s  | 
|  3  | 0.00021100044250488s | 0.00017690658569336s  |  
| Avg | 0.0002122720083s     | 0.0001610120138s      |
```

Here is the updated code:

```
function stuff($elements = []) {
    $output = [];

    // build an array with every unique possible pair
    while ($item = array_shift($elements)) {
        foreach($elements as $element) {
            $possiblePairs[$item.'_'.$element] =  rand(1, 100); // this would be replaced by a function calculating how closely the current elements match
        }
    }
    //use asort to sort on values and 
    asort($possiblePairs, SORT_NUMERIC);         
    $possiblePairs = array_reverse($possiblePairs, true);

    $used = [];
    foreach($possiblePairs as $pair => $score) {
        list($element1, $element2) = explode('_', $pair);
        if($score !== 0 && 
            !in_array($element1, $used) && 
            !in_array($element2, $used)) 
        {
            // save the pair to the output array
            $output[] = [$element1, $element2];
            // store the elements that have already been used
            array_push($used, $element1, $element2);
            if (count($elements) == count($used)) {
               break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly the kind of optimization I was looking for (and dayum those performance gains!)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot avoid doing all possible comparisons, like you do, because you have no knowledge of matching function. It could be written a bit better, by using the natural keys of the array, like this:

```
$possiblePairs = [];
foreach ($elements as $index => $elementA) {
  foreach (array_slice($elements,$index+1) as $elementB) {
    $possiblePairs[] = ['values' => [$elementA, $elementB],
                        'score'  => rand(1,100)]; // matching function
  }
}
```

Then you do a complete sort, that is quite a costly function, and a complete sort is not needed. Think about it, all you need is the best match, after which you can remove all pairs with the same elements as that best match, and then you start again. So, something like this:

```
$output = [];
while (count($possiblePairs) > 0) {
  // find best pair
  $highestScore = 0;
  foreach ($possiblePairs as $possiblePair) {
    if ($possiblePair['score'] > $highestScore) {
      $highestScore  = $possiblePair['score'];
      $bestPair      = $possiblePair;
    }
  }
  // remove used pairs from possible pairs
  foreach (($possiblePairs) as $index => $possiblePair) {
    if (count(array_intersect($possiblePair['values'],$bestPair['values'])) > 0) {
      unset($possiblePairs[$index]);
    }
  }
  // store best pair in output
  $output[] = $bestPair;
}
```

Clearly there are other things we could improve. This code is in global scope, and that's not good. You should use functions or classes. This will isolate the variables from the global scope, which is a good thing, especially when your program grows. So let's make a function:

```
<?php

function BestPairings($elements)
{
  // create all possible parings
  $possiblePairs = [];
  foreach ($elements as $index => $elementA) {
    foreach (array_slice($elements,$index+1) as $elementB) {
      $possiblePairs[] = ['values' => [$elementA, $elementB],
                          'score'  => rand(1,100)]; // matching function
    }
  }
  // output the best pairs
  $output = [];
  while (count($possiblePairs) > 0) {
    // find best pair
    $highestScore = 0;
    foreach ($possiblePairs as $possiblePair) {
      if ($possiblePair['score'] > $highestScore) {
        $highestScore  = $possiblePair['score'];
        $bestPair      = $possiblePair;
      }
    }
    // remove used elements from possible pairs
    foreach (($possiblePairs) as $index => $possiblePair) {
      if (count(array_intersect($possiblePair['values'],$bestPair['values'])) > 0) {
        unset($possiblePairs[$index]);
      }
    }
    // store best pair in output
    $output[] = $bestPair['values'];
  }
  return $output;
}

$elements = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

$output   = BestPairings($elements);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

This last code is complete, it has been tested and works. Just add the excelent suggestions by Sam Onela and it will be great! :-)